# How to disable autostart of SSHD in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, autostart, openssh, sshd

In older versions of Ubuntu I commented out the "start on ..." line in  /etc/init/ssh.conf. This worked well, but not in Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 22):

The command

```
systemctl disable ssh
```

did it for me.

@Jakuje: Thanks for giving me the idea.

Answer (score 8):

This is documented in `man systemctl`:

```
systemctl disable ssh
```

prevents ssh service from automatic starting. But this is the way systemd does it, but ubuntu does not accept it and they have to do it their own way:

Official documentation: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Automatic_starting

According to this you should create unit override without directive `WantedBy=multi-user.target` in `/etc/systemd/system/ssh.service` (instead of the current symlink):

```
rm /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service
cp /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service
sed -e "/WantedBy=multi-user.target/d" -i /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: Commenting out the line as described above "WantedBy=multi-user.target" does not affect the autostart on my system. But after executing "systemctl disable ssh" sshd doesn't start anymore, even it was activated manually in the previous session.

Comment: sure I meant `disable` ... I don't know why I put there `status`. It didn't work for me on Ubuntu (unlike on the other systems) so I was searching also for different solution ...

Comment: Maybe it didn't work in your system because you typed sshd instead of ssh?

Comment: You should prefer the service name `ssh` over its alias `sshd`. For example, `systemctl enable sshd` _doesn't_ work because the aliases [cannot be used to enable services](https://askubuntu.com/a/978868/523336).

Comment: @BeeOnRope thank you for the comment. I am mostly using Fedora/RHEL where it is named `sshd` and which is more self-explaining. I am not sure why Debian/Ubuntu started using just `ssh` for the server. I will edit this answer to reflect it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It does a bit more than requested, but the foolproof approach is to remove the package:

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-server
```

This works in all versions of Ubuntu.

Assuming you have internet access, or have cached the package, reinstalling (and automatically restarting) is not a problem:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall openssh-server`

Answer (score 1):

I want to disable a service and `systemctl disable myservice` doesn't work, but run a `systemctl daemon-reload` after disabling makes it disable.