# Enabling and disabling sshd at boot via systemd

Tags: 16.04, ssh, systemd, openssh

I have `openssh-server` installed but I'd like to sometimes leave the `sshd` service off by default at boot, and only start it from the terminal as needed.

Based on the the advice of [many](https://askubuntu.com/q/19320/523336) other [questions](https://askubuntu.com/q/698993/523336), enabling and disabling the service at boot should be simple on my `systemd` using 16.04 distro:

```
$sudo systemctl disable sshd.service
```

That seems to work. However, I can no longer enable the service at boot after that:

```
$sudo systemctl enable sshd.service 
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
```

Even un-installing and re-installing `openssh-server` doesn't fix it, but a `purge` does.

How do I re-enable `sshd` at boot once I've disabled it via `systemd`?

Note that even in this messed up state I can still manually start and stop the service via `service ssh`[start|stop]`.

Comment: Do you need to re-enable it to start it at boot or do you need to start it from terminal manually only when you need to use it??

Comment: @arryph - admittedly I made the question more confusing by mixing up my original goal and a tangential problem I ran into. My _goal_ was to disable `sshd` at boot and enable it as needed from the terminal. This is actually working since I can use `service ssh start` to start it. However, what I found is that if I want to again enable it at boot via `systemctrl` it doesn't work: the ssh/systemd association seems permanently broken now (solvable via purge which changes all my keys, etc). I edited the question to make it clearer the problem is about `systemctrl enable`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

sshd service is originally written as ssh.service and sshd.service is set as alias name. Check out the last line of following output.

```
arryph@localhost:~$ systemctl cat sshd.service 
# /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/ssh
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=notify

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd.service
```

Because of this, when `ssh.service` is enabled, we can refer it as `sshd.service`. But when you disabled `sshd.service` and rebooted, `ssh.service` is no longer loaded and because of this you can't refer it as `sshd.service` in that condition. You have to refer is as `ssh.service` instead. so if you run `sudo systemctl enable ssh.service`, it will enable `ssh.service` (aliased as `sshd.service`) successfully.

Comment: Excellent, it works. It makes aliases pretty unusable since they work for some commands and not for others.

Comment: that's how service aliases work, you can use them if the service is loaded.

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much!